# Node.js Websocket chat app: clients receiving duplicate message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am new to Node.js. I am trying to implement a chat app using Node.js, websocket. The code I have used on the server side:

```
var config        = require('someconfigure'),
socketServer  = require('somewebsocketapi').server;


var clients = [ ];


socketServer( 'example', function ( connection, server ) {
var index;

  connection.on('open', function ( id ) {
index = clients.push(connection) - 1;
console.log('[open]');
  });



  connection.on('message', function ( msg ) {

    console.log(msg);
    var content = JSON.parse(msg.utf8Data);
    var author = content.action.data[0].author;
    var channel = content.action.data[0].channel;
    var text = content.action.data[0].text;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log(author+text+channel);

    // send messsage to all clients

    var obj = JSON.stringify(
        { 
            command:"messages",
            data: [
                {
                    timestamp: time,
                    text: text,
                    author: author,
                    channel: channel
                }
            ] 
        }
        );
    console.log("Number of clients "+clients.length);
    for (var i=0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if(clients[i]!= connection)
            clients[i].send(obj);
        }
  });

  connection.on('error', function ( err ) {
console.log(err);
  });

  connection.on('close', function(){
   console.log((new Date()) + " Peer "
            + index + " disconnected.");
        // remove user from the list of connected clients
        clients.splice(index, 1);
  });


}).config( config );
```

The problem I am facing is, The clients are getting duplicate messgae. For Example, If 5 clients are connected, then all the client will get the same message 5 times.

I know I am missing up something, But how I can fix this? Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: The problem is that you are storing "connection" (which is for ALL clients) for each client instead of the client itself, so you are sending N times a message for all. Just remove the loop for and you should be fine, or store the actual client in the `on('open', ...)` if you are interested in individual control.

Comment: Then how I can save all the clients seperately?

Comment: I you are using socket.io, then the first parameter of the callback in `on('open', function(socket){});` is "socket", not " id". You should store that. On other implementations I don't know, you probably should check their docs.

Comment: Check this example: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js